# Template for math book

Tags: templates

I really like the template of this math book here

https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-57823-6_1

On the page you have to scroll down and see a preview. It can also be found here

https://archive.org/details/einfuhrungindiea0000brud/page/n11/mode/2up?view=theater

> I wanted to ask if someone can help me recreate this as a *template*.

I tried to remove the chapter using

```
\titleformat{\chapter}{\normalfont\LARGE\bf}{\thechapter.}{5pt}{\LARGE\bf}
```

But this is still not like in the book above. Also, on the second page I really like how it is in the header. Maybe someone has ideas of how to tackle this. That would be great.

I tried to use some online tools to convert pdf to latex but they are really bad...

If you somehow cannot see the preview, here are pictures:

[image]

[image]

Here is part of the code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\usepackage[margin=1.4in]{geometry} 
 \geometry{
bmargin=23mm
 }
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,scrextend}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tikz,tkz-graph,tkz-berge,tikz-cd}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, intersections, backgrounds,calc, arrows}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{sidecap}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{svg.path}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,}
\hypersetup{linkcolor=blue}
\hypersetup{citecolor=Green}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\renewcommand{\blacksquare}{\rule{2mm}{2mm}}
\newtheorem{preremark}{Definition}
\newenvironment{defi}{\begin{preremark}\upshape}{\end{preremark}}
 \newtheoremstyle{dotless}{}{}{\itshape}{}{\bfseries}{}{ }{}
\theoremstyle{dotless}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\newtheorem{thm}{Satz}[chapter]
\newtheorem{hsatz}[thm]{Hauptsatz}
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{prop}[thm]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{kor}[thm]{Korollar}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem*{bsp}{Beispiel}
\newtheorem*{bem}{Bemerkung} 
\newtheorem*{mot}{Motivation}
\newtheorem*{wiss}{Wissenswertes}
\newtheorem*{fol}{Folgerung}
\newtheorem*{beo}{Beobachtung} 
\newtheorem*{nota}{Notation} 
\newenvironment{bew}[1][Beweis]{\smallskip \noindent \textbf{#1.} \setlength{\parindent}{0px}}{\hfill \rule{0.5em}{0.5em}\medskip}
\newenvironment{altbew}[1][Alternativer Beweis]{\smallskip \noindent \textbf{#1.} }{\hfill \rule{0.5em}{0.5em}\medskip}
\makeindex[intoc]
\counterwithout{figure}{chapter}
\usepackage[font={sc}]{caption}
 \usepackage{stackengine, graphicx} %
    \usepackage{mathtools, amssymb, old-arrows}%, relsize}
    \newcommand\twoheadrightarrowtail{\stackMath\mathrel{\mathrlap{\rightarrowtail}\mkern0.3mu\twoheadrightarrow}}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}{\normalfont\LARGE\bf}{\thechapter.}{5pt}{\LARGE\bf}
\begin{document}
\numberwithin{equation}{chapter}

\thispagestyle{empty}
 
\pagenumbering{roman}
\tableofcontents 
\pagestyle{plain}
\newpage
\setcounter{page}{1}
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\chapter{Arithmetische Funktionen und Dirichlet-Reihen}

\section{Primzahlverteilung: eine Einführung}


Die natürlichen Zahlen und auch das Rechnen mit diesen erscheinen nicht nur Mathematikern vertraut, ja selbstverständlich. Primzahlen sind beinahe genauso selbstverständlich. Beim Teilen mit Rest kommen nämlich immer wieder Zahlen vor, die sich nur durch 1 und sich selbst ohne Rest teilen lassen. Dies ist die antike Definition einer Primzahl\footnote{Nach dieser Definition ist $1$ eine Primzahl, was früher durchaus üblich war. Heute wird $1$ nicht zu den Primzahlen gerechnet}. Es überrascht also nicht, wenn schon in frühen Quellen Primzahlen behandelt werden. Zumindest seit Euklid war bekannt, daß Primzahlen die Bausteine der multiplikativen Struktur der natürlichen Zahlen sind, denn jede natürliche Zahl ist ein Produkt von Primzahlen, und dieses Produkt ist auch im wesentlichen eindeutig.\\

...
...
\end{document}
```

Here is the result. The fonts are still too big and there is nothing in the header. The spacing is also not correct and the settings for the chapters and sections neither.

[image]

Comment: The link leads to a springer page where one is free to buy it for a couple of euros just to be able to help. I suggest that you make your question independent of that link.

Comment: @mickep You have to scroll down, there is a preview, I refer to that

Comment: Please post your attempt here, so that everyone doesn't need to retype everything from scratch.

Comment: @calculatormathematical I think that the used fonts are that of the old Computer Modern font.

Comment: @Teepeemm Ok I will do that. I was just afraid that it is too long. I will add my attempt.

Comment: @Sebastiano Good to know. But the font doesnt matter so much. Just the layout, spacing, settings, etc.

Comment: @calculatormathematical, thanks for adding code. However, it‘s better to delete even more packages. It simplifies code and avoids installing unneeded packages, which aren‘t used at all, just to compile your example. It may also be a good idea to add a screenshot of your codes result. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main classes have three fontsize options: 10pt, 11pt, and 12pt.  Since 12pt is too big, you should decrease it.  (But a common mistake is to think there are other size options.  There aren't.)  But I'm also not understanding how you know the font size is too big when your margins are leaving a text width that is much wider than the sample (which is on a page that is not letter or a4).

But the main thing to learn is how to use the package documentation to find what you need.

- `\titleformat` comes from the [titlesec package](https://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec?lang=en).  The package also provide `\titlspacing` commands to adjust vertical spacing before and after headings.
- `\pagestyle{fancy}` uses the [fancyhdr](https://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr?lang=en) settings that you've set (you've set no settings).  I've put in the settings for even numbered pages.  The preview doesn't have odd numbered fancy headings (by default, the first page of a chapter gets `\pagestyle{plain}`).

Some other items:

- Use a blank line, not `\\` , to end a paragraph.
- Use `\bfseries`, not `\bf`.
- You have a large number of packages, nearly all of which aren't needed for the example.  You probably need some of them for your actual project, but try to make sure you only use packages that you need.  It will reduce the chances of package conflicts.

I ended up with:

```tex
\documentclass[11pt,openany]{book}
\usepackage[margin=1.4in,bmargin=23mm]{geometry} 
\usepackage[german]{babel}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[LE]{\thepage\qquad\leftmark}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\thechapter.\ #1}{}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[block]{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thechapter.}{5pt}{\Large\bfseries}
\titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\large\bfseries}{\thesection}{5pt}{\large\bfseries}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{7\baselineskip}

\usepackage[hang,flushmargin]{footmisc} % change the styling of footnotes

\begin{document}
%\frontmatter % to get roman page numbering
%\tableofcontents 
%\setcounter{page}{1}
\mainmatter % to get arabic page numbering

\chapter{Arithmetische Funktionen und Dirichlet-Reihen}

\section{Primzahlverteilung: eine Einführung}

Die natürlichen Zahlen und auch das Rechnen mit diesen erscheinen nicht nur Mathematikern vertraut, ja selbstverständlich. Primzahlen sind beinahe genauso selbstverständlich. Beim Teilen mit Rest kommen nämlich immer wieder Zahlen vor, die sich nur durch 1 und sich selbst ohne Rest teilen lassen. Dies ist die antike Definition einer Primzahl\footnote{Nach dieser Definition ist $1$ eine Primzahl, was früher durchaus üblich war. Heute wird $1$ nicht zu den Primzahlen gerechnet}. Es überrascht also nicht, wenn schon in frühen Quellen Primzahlen behandelt werden. Zumindest seit Euklid war bekannt, daß Primzahlen die Bausteine der multiplikativen Struktur der natürlichen Zahlen sind, denn jede natürliche Zahl ist ein Produkt von Primzahlen, und dieses Produkt ist auch im wesentlichen eindeutig.

\newpage

Some content for a second page

\end{document}
```

This matches the sample, although it's harder to tell because it's not clear what the margins should be and you only provided the first paragraph of text.

Comment: Thanks, I added: 
\fancyhead[RO]{\thepage\qquad\rightmark}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection.\ #1}}